# Get the amount of leading NaN and trailing non NaN values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning, data-preprocessing

I have a dataframe where the rows contain NaN values. The df contains **original columns** namely **Heading 1 Heading 2 and Heading 3** and **extra columns** called **Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 2 and Unnamed: 3** as shown:

| Heading 1 | Heading 2 | Heading 3 | Unnamed: 1 | Unnamed: 2 | Unnamed: 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NaN | 34 | 24 | 45 | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | NaN | 24 | 45 | 11 | NaN |
| NaN | NaN | NaN | 45 | 45 | 33 |
| 4 | NaN | 24 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | NaN | 4 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | 34 | 24 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 22 | 34 | 24 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | 34 | NaN | 45 | NaN | NaN |

I want to **iterate through each row** and find out the amount of **leading NaN values** in **original columns (Heading 1 Heading 2 and Heading 3)** and the amount of **non NaN values** in the **extra columns (Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 2 and Unnamed: 3)**. For each and every row this should be calculated and **returned in a dictionary** where the key is the index of the row and the value for that key is a list containing the amount of **leading NaN values** in **original columns** (Heading 1 Heading 2 and Heading 3) and the second element of the list would the amount of **non NaN values** in the **extra columns** (Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 2 and Unnamed: 3).

So the result for the above dataframe would be:

```
{0 : [1, 1], 
1 : [2, 2], 
2 : [3, 3], 
3 : [0, 0], 
4 : [2, 0], 
5 : [1, 0],
6 : [0, 0],
7 : [1, 1]}
```

**Notice how in row 3 and row 7 the original columns contain 1 and 2 NaN respectively but only the leading NaN's are counted and not the in between ones!**

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative:

```
df['Count'] = df[['Heading 1', 'Heading 2']].apply(lambda x: sum(x.isnull()), axis=1)
df['Count2'] = df[['Unnamed: 1', 'Unnamed: 2']].apply(lambda x: sum(x.notnull()), axis=1)
df['total']=df[['Count','Count2']].values.tolist()

output=dict(zip(df.index, df.total))
'''
{0: [1, 1], 1: [2, 1], 2: [1, 0], 3: [0, 0], 4: [2, 2], 5: [2, 1]}
'''
```

or

```
mask=list(map(list, zip(df[['Heading 1', 'Heading 2']].isnull().sum(axis=1), df[['Unnamed: 1', 'Unnamed: 2']].notnull().sum(axis=1))))
output=dict(zip(df.index,mask))
#{0: [1, 1], 1: [2, 1], 2: [1, 0], 3: [0, 0], 4: [2, 2], 5: [2, 1]}
```

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in my question regarding the requirements of NaN values in original columns. Kindly check the modified question. Sorry for the pain!

Comment: Are the columns fixed ? Will you always have the columns in the question or can new columns be added ?

Comment: For a particular csv/xlsx file, the columns will be fixed. For another csv/xlsx, the no of columns may be different

Comment: but for the current example the columns are fixed

Answer (score 0):

The `.isna()` (in [Cyzanfar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74659427/13001728))  raises an exception for me:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'isna'
```

You could instead try the following:

```
counts = {}

for index, row in df.iterrows():
# Count the number of NaN values in the original columns
num_nan_orig = np.sum(np.isnan(row[['Heading 1', 'Heading 2']]))

# Count the number of non-NaN values in the extra columns
num_non_nan_extra = np.sum(~np.isnan(row[['Unnamed: 1', 'Unnamed: 2']]))

counts[index] = [num_nan_orig, num_non_nan_extra]
print(counts)
```

Outputs the following:

```
# {0: [1, 1], 1: [2, 1], 2: [1, 0], 3: [0, 0], 4: [2, 2], 5: [2, 1]}
```

---

<sup>The **~** operator (third last line in the code) is the bitwise negation operator in Python, which inverts the boolean value of its operand. In this case, it is inverts the boolean values produced by np.isnan() method, so that the non-NaN values can be counted.</sup>

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in my question regarding the requirements of NaN values in original columns. Kindly check the modified question. Sorry for the pain!